# In C# Winforms What is the most precise method of having an asynchronous method guarantee its own execution on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

In doing my research here there seem to be about a million different ways to accomplish this, but the pros and cons of each are less unclear. One possibility that seems to accomplish what I'm after is:

```
private async Task SomeMostlyUIMethod(byte[] someParam = null)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Task result = Task.Run(() => Invoke((Action)(async () => await SomeMostlyUIMethod(someParam))));
        await result;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

That seems to work, it feels like there should be a more clear solution for this. I'm not invoking on a per control modified basis because the method modifies a large number of different UI components, but also need to keep the method asynchronous since it has some expensive non-ui tasks it carries out as well.

Comment: Think about separation of concerns.  You shouldn't need to spin up a task only to invoke back to Gui Thread.  The method SomeMostlyUIMethod should only be working with data not other UI stuff.

Comment: Use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke if you want to be asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

to make work item will be executed on UI thread, you probably need the current synchronization context:

```
factory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

and use that `factory` to `StartNew` any task involved in GUI control updating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the async operation from an UI thread (main thread):

```
await Task.Run(DoYourStuffAsync);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
await Task.Run(DoYourStuffAsync).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

If the boolean argument of ConfigureAwait (`bool continueOnCapturedContext`) is true, the code that is below the await (also called *continuation*) will be executed in the calling thread (UI thread).

What I suggest is to do all your processing in an async way, create an *outcome* object, and then update the UI element in the *continuation* with the *outcome* object.
In this way you are using the UI thread only for UI stuff.